# Send message to JMS Topic in JBoss 7.1 from standalone client, ConnectionFactory not found

Tags: java, junit, jboss, jms-topic

I am having trouble publishing messages and object to my JMS Topic implementation in JBoss 7.1 on a Linux machine from a standalone client. In this case I am testing the connection in a JUnit test case, this:

```
@BeforeClass
  public void setUp() {

 tp = new FlightstatsConsumerTopic(); 
 topic = new JMSTopicSender();
 String client = "ettore";
 String from = "JFK";
 String to = "LHR";
 String date = "2014/5/20"; 
 sample = new FlightRequest(client, from, to, date);
  }

@Test
 public void testRequest() throws IOException, JMSException, NamingException {
 System.out.println("TEST: testing flight request "+ sample.toString());
 topic.sendObject(sample);

 }
```

I am just trying to publish an Object trough the JMS Topic, but I keep getting a NamingException as an output, no matter what.

```
    TEST: testing flight request FlightRequest [client=ettore, departure=JFK, arrival=LHR, date=2014/5/20, connectionType=DIRECT]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[TopicPublisher] Remote Context initilized
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ConnectionFactory -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.ConnectionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:127)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the class that should implement the Publisher for MyTopic:

```
    package commons;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicPublisher;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/RequestSender")
public class JMSTopicSender extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * This class sends a request to the JMS Topic
     */

    // private static final Logger LOG =
    // LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSTopicSender.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TopicConnection conn = null;
    private TopicSession session = null;
    private Topic topic = null;

    public static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY_NAME = "connection.factory.name";

    public JMSTopicSender() {
        super();
    }


    public InitialContext getInitialContext() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "guest");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "guestpassw");
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
            properties.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT",
                        false);
        properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

        try {
            return new InitialContext(properties);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot generate InitialContext");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Set Up a Session with the JMS MyTopic
     * 
     * @throws JMSException
     * @throws NamingException
     */
    public void setupPubSub() throws JMSException, NamingException {

        InitialContext iniCtx = getInitialContext();

        System.out.println("[TopicPublisher] Remote Context initilized");
        try {
            TopicConnectionFactory tmp = (TopicConnectionFactory) iniCtx
                    .lookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");
            conn = tmp.createTopicConnection();
            topic = (Topic) iniCtx.lookup("topic/MyTopic");
        } catch (NamingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JMSException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println("[TopicPublisher] Lookup to ConnectionFactory done.");

        //System.out.println("[TopicPublisher] Lookup to MyTopic done.");
        session = conn.createTopicSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        conn.start();
    }

    /**
     * Send a message text to MyTopic
     * 
     * @param text
     * @throws JMSException
     * @throws NamingException
     */
    public void sendText(String text) throws JMSException, NamingException {
        setupPubSub();
        TopicPublisher send = session.createPublisher(topic);
        TextMessage tm = session.createTextMessage(text);
        send.publish(tm);
        send.close();
    }

    /**
     * Send an object as a Publisher into
     * 
     * @param obj
     * @throws JMSException
     * @throws NamingException
     */
    public void sendObject(Object obj) throws JMSException, NamingException {
        setupPubSub();
        TopicPublisher sender = session.createPublisher(topic);
        ObjectMessage objMsg = session.createObjectMessage();

        objMsg.setObject((Serializable) obj);
        sender.send(objMsg);
    }

    /**
     * Stop the connection and close
     * 
     * @throws JMSException
     */
    public void stop() throws JMSException {
        conn.stop();
        session.close();
        conn.close();
    }
```

The exception is catched when the client tries to do the lookup for the ConnectionFactory, here:

```
 iniCtx.lookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");
```

I have already tried with just "ConnectionFactory", still getting a namingException.
This is my standalone.xml snippet that opens the ConnectionFactory:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
        <hornetq-server>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </netty-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </connectors>

            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </netty-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </acceptors>

            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>

            <address-settings>
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                    <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>

            <jms-connection-factories>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <transaction mode="xa"/>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>

            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="testQueue">
                    <entry name="queue/MyQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-topic name="testTopic">
                    <entry name="topic/MyTopic"/>
                </jms-topic>
            </jms-destinations>
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
```

Did I do somenthing wrong with the InitialContex Properties? I had already looked at a similar answer, but switching to sandalone-full.xml by launching JBoss with:
     sudo bash standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
did not solved the problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to use RemoteConnectionFactory, because your client is not running in the same vm as jboss.

The context lookup should be made to "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" instead of "java:/ConnectionFactory"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
topic = (Topic) iniCtx.lookup("jms/topic/MyTopic");
```

Instead of

```
topic = (Topic) iniCtx.lookup("topic/MyTopic");
```